# SQL to Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone Convert my Sql query into Rails Query???

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversation_cbgs.* FROM "conversation_cbgs" 
INNER JOIN "message_cbgs" 
ON "message_cbgs"."conversation_cbg_id" = "conversation_cbgs"."id"  
INNER JOIN "user_message_cbgs" 
ON "user_message_cbgs"."message_cbg_id" = "message_cbgs"."id" 
WHERE "user_message_cbgs"."user_id" = 1 
ORDER BY conversations_cbgs.updated_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your models built correctly - which would be helpful for those answering your questions, by the way - you would have something like:

```
Conversation.select("DISTINCT conversation_cbgs.*")
  .joins(:messages)
  .joins(:user_messages)
  .where("user_message_cbgs.user_id = ?", 1)
  .order("conversations_cbgs.updated_at DESC")
```

There are other ways using scopes and merges, etc. but you haven't posted any models for us to show you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first establish association between tables.If association is there then show it in question.
Or
You can execute this query by `Model.find_by_sql(sql_query)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ConversationCbg.find(:all, :conditions=>["user_message_cbgs.user_id=?",1], :joins=>"As conversation_cbgs inner join  message_cbgs on message_cbgs.conversation_cbg_id=conversation_cbgs.id inner join user_message_cbgs on user_message_cbgs.message_cbg_id=message_cbgs.id" , :select=>"Distinct conversation_cbgs.*", :order=> "conversations_cbgs.updated_at desc")
```